# How to display an array with ruby nested each?

Tags: ruby

Given a list of array, I want to display *all* pair combination of the array in the form of array of two. For example, let's say I have an array of `[1,2,3]`.

```
[1, 1]
[1, 2]
[1, 3]
[2, 1]
[2, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 1]
[3, 2]
[3, 3]
```

*Expected result*

This is the function I came up with:

```
def all_combination(list)
  list.each do |i|
    list.each do |j|
      puts [i,j]
    end
  end
end

arr1 = [1,2,3] #arr1 can be an array of any size. It will always be integer.
all_combination(arr1)
```

However, when I do the above code, it displays

```
1
1
1
2
1
3
...
```

It seems like there is a gap in my fundamental ruby knowledge. **Why** `puts [i,j]` does not work? How can I make it display an actual array like it shows on *Expected result* section?

I can make it work with `puts "#{i}, #{j}"`, but it does not return an array pair `[a,b]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a builtin method for what you want:

```
[1,2,3].permutation(2).each {|a| p a}
```

If you prefer to stick with your own method (to get "pairs" of items with themselves), change `puts [i,j]` to either `p [i,j]` or to `puts [i,j].to_s`— `puts` works with strings.

Comment: Gotcha! I did not realize that puts work only with strings. I am missing my fundamentals! Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the data on each new line is because puts writes each object given to it on a new line.  [Here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/IO.html#method-i-puts) is the doc on this:

> Writes the given objects to ios as with IO#print. Writes a record
>   separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with
>   a newline sequence. If called with an array argument, writes each
>   element on a new line. If called without arguments, outputs a single
>   record separator.

If Array#permutation does what you want than that is the way to go,  however, I don't think it matches what you asked for (ie [1,1],[2,2],[3,3] will not be included).

The following should provide you with what you were originally asking for.

```
def all_combination(list)
  a = []
  list.each do |i|
    list.each do |j|
      a << [i,j]
    end
  end
  a
end

x = all_combination [1,2,3]
p x
puts x

=> [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3], [3, 1], [3, 2], [3, 3]]
1
1
1
2
1
3
2
1
2
2
2
3
3
1
3
2
3
3
```

x is the returned value you were looking for as shown by p x

ps: this could probably be done with a line or too less using Array#reduce, but this is fairly strait forward.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems like there is a gap in my fundamental ruby knowledge. **Why** `puts [i,j]` does not work?

Why don't we just look at the documentation?

[The documentation for `Kernel#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) simply refers us to the documentation for `IO#puts`:

> ## `puts(obj, …)` → `nil`
>
> Equivalent to
>
> ```
> $stdout.puts(obj, …)
> ```

[The documentation for `IO#puts`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/IO.html#method-i-puts) says this (**bold** emphasis mine):

> ## `puts(obj, …)` → `nil`
>
> Writes the given objects to *ios* as with `IO#print`. Writes a record separator (typically a newline) after any that do not already end with a newline sequence. **If called with an array argument, writes each element on a new line.** If called without arguments, outputs a single record separator.

As you can see, the documentation clearly states that when you pass an `Array` to `puts`, it will print each element on a separate line.

> How can I make it display an actual array like it shows on *Expected result* section?

You cannot display an "actual array". An array is a data structure that maps indices to objects. It's an idea. You cannot display an idea. You can only display text (i.e. a `String`). So, you need to construct a `String` that looks like your desired output.

> I can make it work with `puts "#{i}, #{j}"`, but it does not return an array pair `[a,b]`

Well, it doesn't print the brackets because you didn't tell it to print brackets. It will simply print your `String`, but there aren't any brackets in your `String`, ergo there won't be brackets in the output. You just have to add them:

```
puts "[#{i}, #{j}]"
```

Note: you may be tempted to use [`Array#inspect`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-inspect), [`Array#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-to_s), or [`Kernel#p`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-p), but please don't: their output format is *not* guaranteed. You may get what you expect, but then again, you may not.

`#inspect` is for human-readable debugging output. `Kernel#p` simply calls `#inspect`. In the particular case of `Array#to_s`, it is simply an alias for `Array#inspect`, and the documentation only says:

> ## `inspect` → `string`
>
> ## `to_s` → `string`
>
> Creates a string representation of `self`.
>
> ```
> [ "a", "b", "c" ].to_s     #=> "[\"a\", \"b\", \"c\"]"
> ```

Note that it only says "**a** string representation", but does not guarantee **what** string representation it returns.

The way *I* would approach your problem is something like this:

```
def all_combination(list)
  list.product(list).map {|a, b| "[#{a}, #{b}]" }
end

arr1 = [1,2,3]
puts all_combination(arr1)
```

I mainly did two things:

- Use higher-level collection operations already provided by the Ruby core library ([`Array#product`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-product) and [`Enumerable#map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-map)). This reduces the cognitive overhead of understanding the solution. It's now just one line that clearly tells you what it does: first generate the cartesian product of the list with itself, then transform each pair to a suitable string representation.
- Separate construction of the output from printing the output. This makes it easier to test: you can simply assert that returns the correct value, instead of having it print directly to the screen, and then jumping through hoops to capture the screen output and compare it to some pre-recorded screen output or something like that.

There are still things to improve, though:

- the method does two things: generating the cartesian product and transform it to a string representation
- the method naming: this actually hints at #1 above: how can you find a suitable name that describes precisely what a method does, when the method does multiple things at once?